# CSS rules does not override each other as expected

Tags: css, overriding

I have two (actually three) @media sections in my CSS. From my experience I hoped that one will override each other because it comes later in the CSS file. However this is not the case (on multiple browsers). What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="experts-partition-1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 410px) {

    #experts-partition-1 {
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 970px) {

    #experts-partition-1 {
        width: 0px;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

The browser applies the rules for experts-partition-1 of the first section (min-width: 410px) and not of the second section (min-width: 970px). What might be the reason?

Comment: Change min to max 410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, but the condition is, you have to go above `970px` to work `@media (min-width: 970px)` or you can try `max-width` instead of `min-width` and sequence should be like this

```
@media (max-width: 970px) {

    #experts-partition-1 {
        width: 0px;
        float: right;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 410px) {

    #experts-partition-1 {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

The reason behind using this sequence is the nature of `css`. It works from top to bottom. Hope it helps

Comment: @dsb can you upvote if it helped you? :) thanks for accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Mobile First Approach to design webpage. You have specified a ruleset in this media query

```
    @media (min-width: 410px) {
/* this means rules are applied when the screen size is min 410px and also above that */
    }
```

Mostly in web development there are two approaches 
1. Mobile First
2. Desktop First

Choose one based on the requirement and proceed with it. For better understanding checkout this link about [Mobile First vs Desktop First Approach](https://themeover.com/mobile-first-vs-desktop-first-responsive-design/)